# Specify include path in Quartus II

Tags: intel-fpga, quartus-ii

I'm compiling Verilog using the Quartus II for the Altera platform. In my Verilog, I have a Verilog header `global.vh`, and Quartus II cannot find it:

```
Error (10054): Verilog HDL File I/O error: can't open Verilog Design File "global.vh"
```

Is there a way to specify an "include path" for Verilog header files in Quartus II?

(Note that the header file can be found when placed in the root directory for the Quartus II project.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Altera recommends that you use the SEARCH_PATH assignment to define
>   the project libraries. You can have multiple SEARCH_PATH assignments.
>   However, you can specify only one source directory for each
>   SEARCH_PATH assignment.

For example:

```
set_global_assignment -name SEARCH_PATH "../other_dir/library1"
set_global_assignment -name SEARCH_PATH "../other_dir/library2"
set_global_assignment -name SEARCH_PATH "../other_dir/library3"
```

Please refer to [Managing Quartus II Projects](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii52012.pdf) document for more details.